# HTML5 tags and div tags

Tags: html

For a while now I have been building websites using HTML5 and I love using the new tags it offers.  The ability to avoid using div after div is a wonderful thing and it leads to cleaner and easier to read html.  Something that has me a bit confused is when it's semantically correct to use a div tag. I understand a div is a collection of semantically marked-up content that may need to be grouped together but i've seen numerous ways of writing HTML5 and how programmers use divs and I'm just not sure what's the right way and wrong way or in other words the ok way and the better way.

For example:

```
<div id="header">
    <header>
        <h1>Here is a header!</h1>
    </header>       
</div>

<header id="header">
    <h1>Here is a header!</h1>
</header>
```

Both are ways to write html but is one more semantically correct then the other?  Is it best practice to add a id or class to a header, footer, nav or aside tag and style them, or is that for div tags? Or is it possible i'm just over thinking this? If someone can help put my mind to rest and give me a good understanding, that would be great!

Comment: Good question, and i should also ask: is better to style the div id=header or the header tag for browsers compatibility (like IE8)?

Answer (score 0):

use  tags and use Modernizer.js, so you get IE support.

Answer (score 0):

I think a semantic way to write a header would be something like

```
<header>
    <h1>This is the page heading!</h1>
    <!-- extra header information -->
    <p>A paragraph explaining the page</p>
    <!-- navigation can go into the header, but it doesn't have to -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/example-page">Example page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The key points are that the header element should not be inside of a div#header element, because that is redundant. The header element also doesn't need an id for the same reason.

Comment: the use of `<header id="header">` is perfectly legit